# Select Query from web application times out but completes with an error?

Tags: sql, coldfusion, timeout

Background:

Two nights ago the old-as-hell and very poorly designed website for the company I work for got attacked by a bot that submitted about 5000+ phony orders. In the course of deleting all of those false orders from the database, SQL Management Studio crashed, and the application had to be stopped via task manager and restarted. After that I was getting optimistic concurrence control errors when trying to delete some of the fake records, and had to complete the cleanup via DELETE statement.

(yes, I KNOW it's generally bad practice to delete records from the results pane, but for people like me who aren't actually programmers but get stuck with the IT work because we're the only ones who know how to find the on switch, it makes me less paranoid that I won't delete a record I didn't mean to)

Ever since then, there is a specific page in the admin section of the site that takes a VERY long time to perform a SELECT query for a specific range. The query will complete if you sit there long enough, but here's a screenshot of the ColdFusion error box that comes up with it:

[ColdFusion error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39GKh.png)

I suspect that between the bot attack and Studio Express crashing in the middle of an DELETE query, part of the table is corrupted, which is why it exceeds the allowable time limit. I don't know if our webhost has a backup of the database (I've been in contact with them the last couple days).

What tools can I use to check for and repair errors on that table?

Comment: Did you try SQL Server Profiler to see what the query is?  You could run that in SSMS and check the execution plan to give you an indication as to where the problem might be.

Comment: Thanks. I haven't used that yet, as at this point I have barely a clue what I'm doing (my forte is HTML/CSS, all the tiny bit of SQL I know I've crash-coursed while solving crises).

Comment: Try that to see if it's leftover junk from the attack.  In SQL Studio, select Tools -> SQL Server Profiler.  Connect to the server using the app that opens.  Get ready to run the slow query, then click run, then run the page that crashes.  After it crashes, click the stop icon in the Profiler.  Find the query by in the list (check times).  I suggest you do it when the site is quiet to reduce SQL traffic.

Comment: I'm using Server Management Studio Express 2005, and as far as I know I don't have that option. Is there a way to do it via query?

Comment: No, not that I am aware of.  See https://superuser.com/questions/414662/why-dont-i-have-sql-profiler-on-sql-server-management-studio on how to install profiler. https://expressprofiler.codeplex.com/ appears to be an alternative one, but I have not used it.

Comment: Thanks. I'll have to look into this later tonight when people are less likely to be using the site.

Comment: Or if you don't mind, you can post your query here (mask the table names with fake one). Though the ideal way as @Pieter suggested, but sometimes in old/legacy applications it is obvious mistakes which can be fixed by even a casual look. See if the select query is using * instead of column names. For example if the query is joining 4-5 or more tables and fetching * it would be fetching awful lot of columns for even few records